# Visual Studio Code TS Intellisense for JS Event, File types

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, javascript-intellisense

When trying to do something like,

```
onDragOver(event: Event): void
```

in VS Code, intellisense throws the following error:

> [ts] Cannot find name 'Event'.

the same happens when I try to do something like,

```
let file: File = new File()
```

> [ts] Cannot find name 'File'.

How would I go about removing these errors in VS Code? I'm fairly new to TS and VS Code, so is there some typings declaration that I'm missing?

Comment: Missing `lib:["dom"]` in your tsconfig.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are writing code for browser, add `"dom"` to your `lib` array in your `tsconfig.json`.

For example:

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      ...
    ]
  }
}
```